# Is the solution of this trivial group theory exercise correct?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

If $G$ is a finite group, prove that, given $ a \in G $, there is a positive integer $n$, depending on $a$, such that $a^n=\bf1$, where $\bf1$ is the identity element of the group.

This is my proof:

Since the group is finite, it's not the case that $ \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}, a^m\neq a^n$, therefore $ \exists p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^p=a^q$. Supposing wlog that $p>q$, $a^{p-q}=\bf1$, hence the thesis.

My doubt is about the first assumption. It is intuitive to me that equal two powers of $a$ must exist if the group is finite, but I'm afraid I haven't justified it the proper way.

Comment: It's certainly right. [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) is a bit more generalized.

Comment: your reasoning is true, other wise, powers of $a$ create an infinite sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't quite justified it, though I doubt anyone would argue with it either. The thing to note is that there are *infinitely* many terms $a^m$ and all of them are in a *finite* group - and you certainly can't fit infinitely many distinct terms into a finite set. In fact, with the pidgeonhole principle, you can prove that there is a pair $a^m=a^n$ in the first $|G|+1$ powers of $a$.

Comment: So, could you rewrite my argument in rigorous way?

Comment: If you start with "Since $a^m$ is always in the finite set $G$, by the pidgeonhole principle, $\exists p,q\in\mathbb N such that..." then the proof would be quite nice. (Though nothing fundamentally wrong with your original proof)